# Conditional probablity of poisson sum

Tags: probability, self-study

Let $X_1, X_2,...X_n$ be independent Poisson with parameters $\theta_1, \theta_2..\theta_n$. Let $G=\sum_{i=1}^r X_i$ and $H=\sum_{j=1}^n X_j$ with $r<n$.

I'm interested in getting the conditional probability

$P(G=t|H=u), t \leq u$

I know that both $H$ and $G$ are Poisson with parameters equal to the sums of the parameters of the variables under each of them. My problem is in evaluating $P(G=t \& H=u)$ as numerator of the conditional probability. Is this just equal to $P(G=t)$? My reasoning is something like since $t \leq u$, then $P(G=t or H=u) = P(H=u)$.

Comment: Taking $t=0$ for instance, you seem to be asserting that $\Pr(G=0) = \Pr(G=0, H=0) = \Pr(G=0,H=1)=\cdots=\Pr(G=0,H=u)=\cdots.$ Those equalities cannot all hold unless every probability but one of the form $\Pr(G=0,H=u)$ is zero, which is not the case.  To put it differently: you seem to be saying you have full knowledge of $H$ solely from knowing that $G=t$. Incidentally, your remarks about sums of Poissons indicate you may choose $r=1$ and $n=2$ without any loss of generality.

Comment: Ok. Yeah, I was not sure about that. Can you point me a little to the right direction?

Comment: I believe I just did.  Why not work through a few tiny examples explicitly, such as $u=1,2,3$? Think of the Binomial distribution.  Alternatively, think about what the event $G=t,H=u$ means in terms of a Poisson process: it's counting conditionally independent events.

Comment: So working with that example, I get $P(X1=t,X1+X2=u)=P(X2=u-t)$? So in general, the intersection is the probability that the sum of Xi's from i=r+1 to n is u-t?

Comment: You don't seem to have used the fact that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent. This is a crucial assumption.

Comment: I thought that that assumption is to enable the relationship that the sum of the variables is also Poisson. The fact that X1 and X2 are independent does not mean that X1 is independent from X1+X2, right?

Comment: Let me answer your penultimate comment directly, then: $$\Pr(X_1=t,X_1+X_2=u) = \Pr(X_1=t)\Pr(X_2=u-t).$$  That's what independence allows you to write.

Comment: I would try Bayes' rule, because $P(H=u | G =t)$ and $P(G=t),P(H=u)$ are easy - these are sums of $n-r, r$ and $n$ Poissons, respectively.

Comment: @whuber Awesome! Thank you for that. Actually, my first consideration while working on the problem was $u-t$ but I couldn't make sense of it because it did not look right. The fact that $Pr(X1=t,X1+X2=u)=Pr(X1=t, X2=u-t)$ was what I was missing. The answer does simplify to a form similar to binomial pmf except that the probability of success is the sum of the Poisson parameters from 1 to r.